# merge the 3 cells data into one and write to another csv

Tags: python

I am trying to read one csv file and write the data to another file. while duing this i am facing some problem. I want to merge the 3 cells data into one and write to another csv file. Please see my code below with csv input file and output file.

```
import csv
# initialize with empty ints and dicts
name, date_, indus ,nike1, nike2, nike3, paid, _abbr =[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]

with open('company_inf1.csv','rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    reader.next() #skip header
    for row in reader:
        name.append(row[0])
        date.append(row[1])
        indus.append(row[2])
        nike1.append(row[3])
        nike2.append(row[4])
        nike3.append(row[5])
        paid.append(row[6])
        abbr.append(row[7])

cn = list(name)
date = list(date)
indus = list(indus)
inf1 = list(nike1)
inf2 = list(nike2)
inf3 = list(nike3)
paid = list(paid)
abr = list(abbr)

a = [(inf1), (inf2), (inf3)]
b = [int(i[0]) for i in a]
c = [int(i[1]) for i in a]
d = [int(i[2]) for i in a]
t =((b),(c),(d))
with open('test123.csv','w') as cfile:
    writer = csv.writer(cfile, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(['id','name', 'date','indus','nike', 'paid ', 'abbr'])
    for i,x in enumerate(cn):
        writer.writerow([i,x ,date[i],indus[i],t,paid[i],abr[i]])
```

My Csv File is

```
Name    Date    Indus   nike1   nike    nike3   Paid    absr
XYZ 30-06-1987  Service 1   2   3   10000   abs
abc 01-02-1986  MAN 4   5   6   sasa    sa
def 02-02-1985  Abc 7   8   9   saassas qw
jhk 01-02-2002  adads   10  11  12  saasas  qwws
```

Output is

```
id  name    date    industry    neki    paid abbr

0   XYZ ########    Service ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9])   10000   abs 

1   abc ########    MAN ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9])   sasa    sa  

2   def ########    Abc ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9])   saassas qw
```

Output should be

```
id  name    date    industry    sector  paid    abbr

0   XYZ ########    Service ([1, 2,3])  10000   abs 

1   abc ########    MAN ([4, 5, 6]) sasa    sa  

2   def ########    Abc ([7, 8, 9]) saassas qw
```

can any body can help me?

Comment: Have you walked through this will a debugger?  Try adding `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` on the first line, and use the "n" command to step.  You can use the "p" command to display what you'd want to see, or type "help" for the debugger commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple solution, which combines all the `nike`'s together and write within one loop:

```
import csv

with open('company_inf1.csv','rb') as csvfile, open('out.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerow(['id','name', 'date','indus','nike', 'paid', 'abbr'])
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    reader.next() # skip header
    for id, (name, date, industry, nike1, nike2, nike3, paid, abbreviation) in enumerate(reader):
        nike = '([{0},{1},{2}])'.format(nike1, nike2, nike3)
        writer.writerow([id, name, date, industry, nike, paid, abbreviation])
```

A few notes:

- I combined the two loops into one, which speeds things up a little and use less memory because I don't have to store the file contents in lists. This is important if your file is large.
- In general, I don't abbreviate variable names, unless it is very long.
- As a matter of personal preference, I don't only specify a delimiter when creating a CSV reader or writer when it is not a comma.

Answer (score 2):

The following should work. Note the complete removal of all of these lines:

```
a = [(inf1), (inf2), (inf3)]
b = [int(i[0]) for i in a]
c = [int(i[1]) for i in a]
d = [int(i[2]) for i in a]
t = ((b),(c),(d))
```

and the addition of the line:

```
t = (map(int, (inf1[i], inf2[i], inf3[i])),) # merge three columns together
```

to the`for i,x in enumerate(cn):`loop. I also fixed a few misnamed variables.

```
import csv
# initialize with empty ints and lists
name, date_, indus, nike1, nike2, nike3, paid, _abbr = [[] for _ in xrange(8)]

with open('company_inf1.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    reader.next() # skip header
    for row in reader:
        name.append(row[0])
        date_.append(row[1])
        indus.append(row[2])
        nike1.append(row[3])
        nike2.append(row[4])
        nike3.append(row[5])
        paid.append(row[6])
        _abbr.append(row[7])

cn = list(name)
date = list(date_)
indus = list(indus)
inf1 = list(nike1)
inf2 = list(nike2)
inf3 = list(nike3)
paid = list(paid)
abr = list(_abbr)

with open('test123.csv', 'w') as cfile:
    writer = csv.writer(cfile, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(['id', 'name', 'date', 'indus', 'nike', 'paid', 'abbr'])
    for i,x in enumerate(cn):
        t = (map(int, (inf1[i], inf2[i], inf3[i])),) # merge three cols together
        writer.writerow([i, x, date[i], indus[i], t, paid[i], abr[i]])
```

I think it would be better to just read the input file and write the output file at the same time inside one`for`loop because it would be simpler and eliminate the need to read and store all the data into memory at once (so there wouldn't be so many variables).

Here's what I mean:

```
import csv

with open('company_inf1.csv', 'rb') as inf, open('test123.csv', 'w') as outf:
    reader = csv.reader(inf, delimiter=',')
    reader.next() # skip header
    writer = csv.writer(outf, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(['id', 'name', 'date', 'indus', 'nike', 'paid', 'abbr'])
    for i, (name, date, indus, nike1, nike2, nike3, paid, abbr) in enumerate(reader):
        t = (map(int, (nike1, nike2, nike3)),) # convert & merge together 3 cols
        writer.writerow([i, name, date, indus, t, paid, abbr])
```

Comment: thanks i reaaly very use full  t = (map(int, (inf1[i], inf2[i], inf3[i]))) but i want to pass string what should to do

Comment: when i passing string in nike 1 nike 2 and nike 3 i am getting below error C:\Python27>python jaimatadi.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jaimatadi.py", line 10, in <module>
    t = (map(int, (nike1, nike2, nike3)),) # map & merge the 3 cols together
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'sector'

Comment: Everything is read in from a csv as a string and converted to a string when it's written, so I'm not sure what you mean. Maybe you could try `t = str(map(int, (nike1, nike2, nike3)),)`.

Comment: `'sector'`? What's that? Regardless, the error message means that something in fields `nike1`, `nike2`, or `nike3` isn't a valid base 10 integer digit. It would happen in your original code, too, in one of the `[int(i[0]) for i in a]` lines which tries to do the same thing to each of the three fields.

Comment: I like using a `DictReader/DictWriter`, but this is good too.

Comment: @Rohit: I think it's unfair that you switched your accepted answer to another, much later one, which is almost identical.